# Will add exogenous alter the hyper parameters of a SARIMA model?

Tags: python, time, series

If you have done optimizing the hyper parameters of a SARIMA model, do you need to find the optimal p, d, q, and P, D, Q again if you add exogenous variables?

Thanks
Wu

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pleases note that Python is a general-purpose programming language, not a data science language. You're going to have to provide a lot more detail (and possibly add relevant tags) if you're going to get an answer here. I'm not even sure that this is a programming question; it might be completely off-topic.

Comment: I was doing a generic SARIMAX model with sale as dependent variable while advertising spend as independent variable. Both has upward trend and with seasonal patterns. I did a gradient search for p, d, q, P, D, Q with the dependent variable only. It took several days.Now I want to add the independent variable. I just wondering if I need to do a gradient search of all hyper parameters again. In other word, does adding exogenous alters the hyper parameters?

This question is independent of Python. It is more about SARIMA model itself.

Comment: I got order = (0,1,1) and seasonal_order=(01,6,12) without the exogenous.